# Creating a search bar that has dropdown options .Net MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, model-view-controller

I am creating a website using .NET and C# MVC forms. Currently, I would like to create a search bar that when given a string it will have a dropdown of possible options. For instance if I type A, the drop down will show Apple, Automotive, Alphabet. If it is Ap, then it will only show Apple. I figure that I would need some javascript but if possible, I could use alittle help. I tried looking online but maybe I worded wrong because I could find the correct solution. For instance, it would look something like this image. Thank you so much.

[image]

Comment: Here is a w3schools walkthrough https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp

Comment: This is popular https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/